# Deploy Java EE application to payara41 docker container using maven

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, docker, glassfish-4

I am trying to deploy a simple maven-based java web application into a payara 41 application server running on a docker container. To do so I am using the Glassfish Maven Plugin with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <glassfishDirectory>/path/to/local/payara41/glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>admin</user>
                <adminPassword>MyPassword</adminPassword>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <echo>true</echo>
                <domain>
                    <name>payaradomain</name>
                    <adminPort>4848</adminPort> <!-- mandatory for mvn glassfish:deploy -->
                    <httpPort>8080</httpPort> 
                    <httpsPort>8181</httpsPort>
                    <host>DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP</host>
                    <jvmOptions> 
                        <option>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/login.conf</option> 
                    </jvmOptions> 
                    <properties> 
                        <property> 
                            <name>server.log-service.file</name> 
                            <value>${domain.log.dir}/server.log</value> 
                        </property> 
                    </properties>
                    <resourceDescriptor>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/setup/glassfish-resources.xml</resourceDescriptor> 
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see I'm using the host property in the domain configuration because I'm trying to deploy to a docker container, which is a remote domain (this could be wrong, if so you can correct me).

The thing is when I try to deploy the app I get the following Output:

```
Domain payaradomain isn't started. Starting it for you.
Domain payaradomain does not exist. Creating it for you.
[/path/to/local/payara41/glassfish/bin/asadmin, create-domain, --echo=true, --terse=true, --interactive=false, --user, admin, -- passwordfile, /tmp/mgfp5897945230218013760.tmp, --domaindir,  /path/to/local/payara41/glassfish/domains, --profile, developer, -- adminport, 4848, --instanceport, 8080, --domainproperties,  http.ssl.port=8181, payaradomain]
CLI031: Warning: Option "profile" is obsolete and will be ignored.
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile   /tmp/mgfp5897945230218013760.tmp --interactive=false --echo=true -- terse=true create-domain --adminport 4848 --profile developer --domaindir   /path/to/local/payara41/glassfish/domains --instanceport 8080 --  savemasterpassword=false --usemasterpassword=false --domainproperties   http.ssl.port=8181 --savelogin=false --nopassword=false --checkports=true   payaradomain
CLI130: Could not create domain, payaradomain
Unable to create domain "payaradomain".
For more detail on what might be causing the problem try running maven   with the --debug option 
or setting the maven-glassfish-plugin "echo" property to "true".
```

As you can see maven is trying to deploy the app locally. I think something is wrong with the configuration of the Maven Glassfish Plugin.
I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2, Apache Maven 3.0.5 and Java 8

**EDIT**
I ran maven with --debug option, but got same output. I think it is not a matter of system rights. What's interesting is that I think maven is trying to execute this command:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile     /tmp/mgfp2052757567130924436.tmp --interactive=false --echo=true --  terse=true create-domain --adminport 4848 --profile developer --domaindir   /path/to/local/payara41/glassfish/domains --instanceport 8080 --  savemasterpassword=false --usemasterpassword=false --domainproperties   http.ssl.port=8181 --savelogin=false --nopassword=false --checkports=true   payaradomain
```

where localhost is set as the --host option, I think maven has not picked up this option from the configuration. Maybe I'm missing something.

The thing is my local payara is not running and perhaps that's why it can't create the payaradomain. But on the docker container, which is running, this domain exists already

Comment: I updated the output because the first one was simple telling me that I didn't hava java installed which I did, it just wasn't in the inveronment variables. Once fixed that same issue. Looks like maven is trying to deploy the application locally.

Comment: I ran maven with --debug option, but got same output. I think it is not a matter of system rights. I updated my question.

Comment: The thing is my local payara is not running and perhaps that's why it can't create the payaradomain. But on the docker container, which is running, this domain is created already.

Comment: Based on that added output it seems likely the deploy is being interpreted as a local deploy and not a remote deploy. So it becomes a question of figuring out what the magic command is to get a remote deployment going. I'm thinking that warning *CLI031: Warning: Option "profile" is obsolete and will be ignored.* is at the heart of it. You may be needing to use a newer version of the maven glassfish plugin to match your server version. EDIT: except that 2.1 is the last version.

Comment: You could workaround the problem by port forwarding 4848 from the container to 4848 locally. I'm not sure about the Maven plugin configuration, but the asadmin command is already communicating to a "remote" server, it's just that it happens to think the remote server is on localhost. Doesn't fix it, but should get you going.

Comment: @Mike your aproach did work but now the output has changed to `remote failure: File not found : /home/myusername/NetBeansProjects/myapp/target/myapp.war
Deployment of /home/myusername/NetBeansProjects/myapp/target/myapp.war failed.`
I googled around and found that this issue might be because of systems permissions on myapp.war but I already checked that. Can anything else be causing this new problem?

Comment: I believe it's because what is actually happening is that your local asadmin sends the deploy command to the remote asadmin, which then executes the actual deploy, so it's looking for that file on the remote system (i.e. in your docker container). If you [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/) the WAR over, that will probably work.

Comment: At this stage, though, it's probably going to be easier for you to just copy the file over to the autodeploy folder in the container (`payara41/glassfish/domains/payaradomain/autodeploy`). The deployment scanner will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not treat the docker container as a "remote deploy" but rather publish all needed ports on the host (see -p option of the run command), and just deploy locally.

Comment: I removed the host property from the configuration and it works, but only if I fun the application (combined with @Mike's comment). If I perform a clean and build I get the same error as before.